# iOS SDK / AdMob / AdColony mediation adapter

Tags: ios, admob, adcolony

I´m using AdMob as the main ad network. Now i want to include "some" mediation adapters. One of them is "AdColony" which is video based. It works fine, but i want to do some improvements as i don´t want to show a video clip of 30 seconds every time. I can´t find a way to solve it. Maybe someone can help me on this. The structure is like this:

1) I have a quiz app - on every "level" a view will be loaded.

2) When the view is loaded, the ad network will be loaded like this

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
        self.interstitial = [self createAndLoadInterstitial];
}

- (GADInterstitial *)createAndLoadInterstitial {

    GADInterstitial *interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:kSampleAdUnitID];

    interstitial.delegate = self;

    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

    [interstitial loadRequest:request];

    return interstitial;

}
```

3) An ad will be loaded

4) The ad will be shown as soon as the level is done.

```
- (IBAction)showInterstitial:(id)sender {     
    if (self.interstitial.isReady) {
            [self.interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
    } else {

        NSLog(@"ADMOB - The interstitial didn't finish loading or failed to load");
 }  
}
```

5) When the level is done, the view will be unloaded and everything starts from the beginning.

The problem is, that everytime the AdColony adapter will be loaded. My idea is to load the AdColony adapter every 5-10 times and the other times, the admob or other adapter will be called. I tried to add it in the backend of AdColony, but without any luck. Can somehelp me on this?

PS. Can anyone recommend another adwork which works with AdMob ans is easy to integrate?

Answer (score 0):

There are settings in the AdColony dashboard system to solve the issues you mention.

To limit the length of videos shown, you will need to work with AdColony Support to set this up as it is a network administrator setting.  Email us at support@adcolony.com to get started on this.

To have our SDK show a video every X number of requests to play, go into your app's zone settings on the dashboard and input the desired frequency in the Play Frequency option.  Note, this is only available for interstitial zones.

Comment: Thats correct, but instead of showing nothing I want to show other ad networks